# What is going on with this user’s SO reputation?

Tags: discussion, users

I found a user on here, via a comment they made and clicked on their profile, which lead to profile with apparently conflicting information, which confused me.

The user's actual SO profile has ~1,000 rep and 1-3 gold badges; yet their profile contains an image with their info (and same username) with ~10,000 rep and 3-4 gold badges. I thought perhaps this image came from their combined total rep across all of SE, **but network profiles don't work like that.**

Now, I'm not saying he IS falsifying, I just THINK he might be... I'm being intentionally vague because I don't want to unintentionally create a false allegation, but what is going on?

Comment: What do you mean by "falsifying".  Sounds like the user in question has multiple accounts, one with 1000 rep and another with 10K.  Note that having multiple accounts isn't against the rules

Comment: Was it a flair image? Because we provide a network-wide flair that does display your reputation and badges across all sites. You can find it in your edit profile pages.

Comment: @NonCreature0714 sounds like you were looking at their flair as StephenRauch's answer suggests

Comment: Why downvotes? It’s an honest question, and so few people use flair on their profiles it shouldn’t come as a surprise when someone (me) is confused after never seeing it on a profile before. I also didn’t tarnish anyone, or attack them, and didn’t create extra work for a moderator by submitting a report which would turn out to be false. I would bet that some reading this have never seen flair before either.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That is their Flair!  Yours looks like this:

[image: Flair]

Comment: So you are also falsifying SO reputation @NonCreature0714 ...

Comment: @rene you caught me :/

Comment: How do you see ones flair? @NonCreature0714

Comment: @TheOneWhoMade check out the comment by animuson

Comment: No im asking how you see other's flair. Sorry for not clarifing. @NonCreature0714

Comment: Click the link for the one here.  In the address bar you will see a number.  That is the users network id, which you can get from their network profile page url.

Comment: Just to clarify for others, my response to @rene is humor, because I interpret their comment as humor.

Comment: https://stackexchange.com/users/flair/9107868.png @StephenRauch

Comment: @TheOneWhoMade - Yes, the only accounts on your flair are ones with more than 200 reputation.

Comment: @TheOneWhoMade: https://stackexchange.com/users/flair/12513750.png You need to use the Network ID, not the SO id.

Comment: Where do I find the netwok ID? @StephenRauch

Comment: URL of Network Profile, which is another page in which you can also find your own flair: https://stackexchange.com/users/12513750/theonewhomade

Comment: So it would be on the universal site. Thanks! @StephenRauch